# Jquery slideshow - time on initial image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple JQuery slide-show (basically copied from http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow).

The total time spent on each image is 6 seconds. Of this the time spent transitioning to the next image (via linear fade) is 4 seconds, meaning the time you see each image without any fading going on is 2 seconds. This is fine.

However when the page is initially loaded the first image is not fading from anything so it will sit there for the full 6 seconds before transitioning to the second image. Because every other image only has 2 seconds where you see them without animated fading, it appears as though the initial image is being displayed for much longer than the other images.

I'd like the first image to be shown for only 2 seconds, so that the time it's displayed without transition effects is the same as the other images.
How would I make the time spent on the very first slide to be only 2 seconds, and then change back to 6 seconds for the rest?

Script:

```
<script src="js-jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.frontSlide img:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){
            $('.frontSlide :first-child').fadeOut(4000, 'linear')
            .next().fadeIn(4000, 'linear')
            .end().appendTo('.frontSlide');},
        6000);
    });
</script>
```

Css:

```
.frontSlide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.frontSlide img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Body:

```
<div class="frontSlide">
    <img src="01.jpg" />
    <img src="02.jpg" />
    <img src="03.jpg" />
    <img src="04.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use `setInterval()`, you can use the callbacks of the animation functions to chain the animations. Unfortunately, the `.delay()` function does not appear to support a callback that gets executed when it completes --- like the other animation functions do --- but the `.queue()` function can be used for that purpose. You just have to remember to call `.dequeue()` inside the callback function.

```
$(function() {
    function showNextSlide($slide) {
        var $nextSlide = $slide.next();
        if ($nextSlide.length == 0) {
            $nextSlide = $slide.siblings(':first');
        }
        $nextSlide.fadeIn(2000, 'linear').delay(2000).queue(function() {
            showNextSlide($(this).dequeue().fadeOut(2000, 'linear'));
        });
    }

    $('.frontSlide>:gt(0)').hide();

    $('.frontSlide>:first').delay(2000).queue(function() {
        showNextSlide($(this).dequeue().fadeOut(2000, 'linear'));
    });
 });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk6karLx/4/)

---

The code above does not move the images within the container, but it makes for more lines of code. Here is a version that moves the images like your original code.

```
$(function() {
    $('.frontSlide>:gt(0)').hide();
    $('.frontSlide>:first').delay(2000).queue(function(next) {
        next();
        (function fadeSlide() {
            $('.frontSlide>:first').appendTo('.frontSlide').fadeOut(2000, 'linear');
            $('.frontSlide>:first').fadeIn(2000, 'linear').delay(2000).queue(function(next) {
                next();
                fadeSlide();
            });
        })();
    });
 });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk6karLx/5/)

Comment: This has a different effect than the original, which had the next image fade in while the current fades out.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk - Thanks. I did miss that. I still wouldn't use `setInterval()`, but I will work on something that uses `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I'm not too fussed about completely accurate timings; as long as it's not too noticeable it's fine.

Comment: @JohnS my original implementation did have a delay due to the difference between the setInterval and the fadeOut/fadeIn times; I adjusted your timings in the first solution to match it. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the same code before the interval and wrap it in a `setTimeout` of 2 seconds:

```
<script src="js-jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.frontSlide img:gt(0)').hide();
        setTimeout(function() {
            fade();
            setInterval(fade, 6000);
        }, 2000);
        function fade() {
            $('.frontSlide :first-child').fadeOut(4000, 'linear')
            .next().fadeIn(4000, 'linear')
            .end().appendTo('.frontSlide');
        }
    });
</script>
```